# Can't update event data in full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use fullcalendar.js this is my code:

```
      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    console.log(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format() + "|" + event.end.format());
    event.start = moment(event.start.format());
    event.end = moment(event.end.format());
    console.log(event.start);
    console.log(event);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
  },
```

Same you see, when i drop event, it will execute this function, event.start.format() print new data event, but when i print event.start , it remain show old data. So i decide to assign directly event.start=moment(event.start.format()), but when i print again event, inspect it in firebug, so "start attribute" of event variable not change, i am confuse why is it so ?. Thank advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) - you've got it all screwy, which I'm guessing errors out your code and stops it from updating

```
console.log(event.title + " was dropped on " + moment(event.start).format());
```

Comment: may i make you hard to understand, but look at code, this is i actually want to do why event.start change value, when console.log(event) event not change value. it make me confuse